# Error edit() must be an instance of App\User, none given

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i created a UserController.php

```
use App\User;
//

class UsersController extends Controller
{
//

    public function edit($id, User $user){
      $user = $user->find($id);
      return view('admin.user.edit' , compact('user'));
    }

 //


}
```

And edit views

but when i want to access to this url

```
url('/users/'. $user->id .'edit')
```

i got this error

> Error edit() must be an instance of App\User, none given

!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your route is like:

```
Route::get(/users/{id}/edit', 'UsersController@edit');
```

Then use it as:

```
url('/users/'. $user->id .'/edit');
```

or

```
url("/users/{$user->id}/edit");
```

And then your controller should be as:

```
public function edit($id) {
  $user = User::find($id);
  return view('admin.user.edit' , compact('user'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the edit() function expects $user_id and User instance but you're only providing $user_id. If that's the case your code should look like this:

```
public function edit($id){
      $user = User::find($id);
      return view('admin.user.edit' , compact('user'));
}
```